# RxJava - how to invoke subscriber on 4 click events in Android

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

In android I have a text view defined like this:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/text1"       
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/hello_world"
     android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
     android:textIsSelectable="true" />
```

My goal is that after it is clicked 4 times, I want to start a new activity. I need to do this with RXJava; this is a requirement. Or `rxAndroid`, `rxBinding`, etc.

My activity looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements onClickListener {
    TextView tv;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        tv.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.text1){

        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: 
but this is just the standard way of doing it. There must be a way to do with with reactive rxJava API.

So instead of using a `onClicklistener` with `rxBinding` I read we can do this:

```
RxView.clicks(tv).flatMap(tv -> { 
        // another observable which can throw onError. 
        return Observable.error(null); 
    }).subscribe(object -> { 
        Log.d("CLICK", "textview clicked", start activity);
    }, error -> { 
        Log.d("CLICK", "ERROR");
    });
```

Can I somehow use a command in `rxBinding` to make it execute only after 4 clicks?  I'm not looking to store a static variable, or use a anonymous class and store a member variable for count in it.  There should be an observable method for this.

Comment: You are trying to achieve quadruple click or just 4 clicks with unspecified amount of time between them?

Comment: quadruple click, but i can settle for 4 clicks with a time limit between. that works just as good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create an observable to emit each time the button is clicked, then count the total times it has emitted, and use a filter so that your subscriber will only see it once it has emitted four times.

```
Observable<View> buttonObservable = ViewObservable.clicks(initiateButton, false);
buttonObservable.count()
        .filter(count -> (count >= 4))
        .subscribe(object -> {
            //Your code here
        });
```

Comment: The `Observable.count` method just returns the number of times the `Observable` has emitted an item. It's part of RxJava

Comment: count can't be used here because it will only emits an item after it's observable emits completed (http://rxmarbles.com/#count)

the click observable on the other hand is infinite

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve with something like this:

```
Observable.create((Observable.OnSubscribe<Void>) subscriber -> {
    if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> subscriber.onNext(null));
    }
}).buffer(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .filter(clicks -> clicks.size() == 4)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(clicks -> {
            Log.d("CLICK", "CLICK");
        });
```

- `buffer()` - gather clicks for 1s window
- `filter()` - filter all emitted buffered items, where is number of items in buffer not equal 4 (disable double, triple, quintuple clicks)

The hardest part is to specify buffer time "window". One second is sometimes not enough, but in other cases user have to wait few milliseconds.

Comment: What is "create((Observable.OnSubscribe<Void>"? Im using rxjava2

Comment: @PabloCegarra This is example is based on RxJava1. Method `create()` is used, when you need create observable from some provider (`OnClickListener` in this case).  `Observable.OnSubscribe<Void>` is just type definition of the subscriber. In RxJava2 you should use `Flowable`.

Comment: Can you update your post to rxjava2 please? I will vote you if it works, now Im using rxbinding just for this

Comment: @PabloCegarra Please, create a new question and specify there your requirements. Someone take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

For detecting multiple clicks with a sensible timeout (eg. 4 clicks within 1000 ms), the following works well:

```
    final int numClicks = 4;
    final int timeout = 1000;
    disposables.add(RxView.clicks(tv)
            .buffer(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, numClicks)
            .filter(list -> list.size() == numClicks)
            .subscribe(this::doThing));
```

In this example the `buffer` will either emit 4 events, or emit fewer than 4 events every 1000ms, which will be ignored because of `filter`

Comment: this is pretty good,thanks, but isns't it the same as Zygi answer ?

Comment: I tried that one initially and I couldn't get it to work. Even if it did work, this answer had a couple of advantages for me: 1. you can do it in one line; 2. the version of `buffer` which includes the timeout as well as numClicks works perfectly for the "multiple click" scenario

Comment: @Peter This will wait for a second to complete before giving the result. What if I want to get the result as soon as 4 clicks are done within the 1 second timeframe?

Comment: @RishabhJain are you certain? according to the documentation for `buffer`, the items will be emitted when either `timespan` (timeout in the example above) is reached OR `count` (numClicks above) is reached - so when 4 clicks are received in the above example the observer should be called regardless of how much time has elapsed: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html

Answer (score 1):

@skywall answer is the most complete, however if you don't care about time intervals the simplest answer will be to use [skip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/skip.html)

```
Observable<Void> fourClicksView = RxView.clicks(tv).skip(3); 
fourClicksView.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: It depends if you need exactly 4 clicks and not more. Question has been stated exactly as quadruple click.

Comment: The question required 4, of course it can be changed as desired, if you only want one event you can also use first() or take(1) afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Use buffer and debounce operator.

```
val clickStream = RxView.clicks(view)
    clickStream.buffer(clickStream.debounce(250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            .map { it.size }
            .filter { it == 4 }
            .subscribe({
            })
```

Comment: RxView.clicks(view).share() - rxbinding operate only with last listener, more here https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/issues/146

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start an activity after some number of clicks within a time window, then try this:

```
RxView.clicks(tv)
    .map(e -> SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())
    .buffer(NUM_CLICKS, 1) //Grab every sub-sequence of however many clicks
    .filter(times -> times.size() == NUM_CLICKS) //Last values will be truncated
    .filter(times -> times.get(NUM_CLICKS - 1) - times.get(0) < ALLOWED_TIME) //check times
    .subscribe(ignore -> startActivity());
```